# Populate checkbox dynamically and on tick function calls server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I need to create a table with dynamically populated rows of checkbox. 
The checkbox list will change according to the company they are in

e.g:  1st company : Apple friends

```
 Name     email        iPhone   iPad  macbook  macpro 
 john  jo@mail.com      ckb      ckb     ckb      ckb
 Mel   mel@mail.com     ckb      ckb     ckb      ckb
```

2nd company : Mirco Friends

```
 Name     email        windows   office 
 jav   jav@mail.com      ckb      ckb    
 Kel   Kel@mail.com      ckb      ckb
```

If that is doable how do i go about creating a method to catch any on change event for the checkboxes?

A normal checkbox change function:

```
$('#checkbox1').change(function())
```

But how do we write codes or ids for checkboxes that are defined dynamically?

I know these seems like 2 Questions but the second question is tied with the first.

Appreciate your help

Comment: how you generate the checkbox? maybe some html code can help to troubleshoot, you might can assign a unique id(name) as an id for the checkbox

Comment: i can have dynamically populated checkbox with unique ids, but i cant write dynamically generated codes to handle it's on tick event.

Comment: You might can try to get all the checkbox that is `:checked`, I assume only the checked need to do some code, then get the checkboxid that is generate dynamic by your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly the idea is, loop through every single checkbox that is checked, and then get the id of the checkbox, if you can get the id, I believe you can easily do anything you want using the id that you got

```
$(':checked').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    console.log($this.attr('id'));

});
```

**Updated**

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    console.log($this.attr(id)); // u get the id here if any checkbox is tick/untick

    if ($this.prop("checked")){
        //do something when it is checked
    }else{
        //do something when it is unchecked
    }

});
```

Comment: Sorry if i didnt specify properly, it's on change event, so if any checkbox is untick it should fire as well. It's possible to loop through all the items, however i will not be able to know which is the checkbox that has just change it's state.

Comment: I updated with a new js code, not sure if this the thing that you want

Comment: when is $(':checkbox').change(function()) Fired? Upon any checkbox.change event ? If it is then it's perfect

Answer (score 0):

You may Try like

```
$(document).on('change', '#checkbox1', function() {
alert('alerted');
});
```

Comment: I cant use '#checkbox1' Its dynamically populated. Unless the id can be returned on ANY checkbox's ontick event

Comment: show your code. how you create checkboxes dynamically.

Comment: logically id can not be same for more than one checkbox. So I suggest you should use Class or Name of the checkbox.

Comment: i am not sure i am right. But any how look into this fiddle it may help you http://jsfiddle.net/hjw6S/